# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run /mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-ec2

Am working in a previously created ec2 instance. MySQL, Apache & PHP are already installed.
Am logged in as admin using PuTTy SSH, but after running

```
 mysql -u root -p
```

and entering the password it gives the error

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run   /mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")
```

Please guide...Thanks in advance

Comment: Your config /etc/my.cnf  /etc/mysql/my.cnf somewhere has a space in the socket path between `/var/run` and `/mysqld/mysqld.sock`. Find it and remove the space.

Comment: @danblack How can I find it?

Comment: `grep socket /etc/my*`